# How to solve CORS error while fetching an external API?

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, fetch-api

I'm developing a web app in Angular 10 that works as follows:

[image: Architecture illustration]

I'm dealing with CORS issue. I do not have permission to add code to the server I'm fetching.

I want to be able to:

1. Fetch the website
2. Parse the result, and put it in my database

I'm aiming to deploy the solution on an Apache server.

Here is the CORS error I'm dealing with:

> Blocking a Cross-Origin Request: The "Same Origin" policy does not
> allow viewing the remote resource located at
> https://wwwfrance1.CENSORED.eu.com/api/?apikey=CENSORED.
>
> Reason: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CORS header is missing. Status
> code: 200.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Using MOSIF Mozilla extension (works, but not sustainable for deployment, and for some reason, when I'm ignoring the CORS security, I cannot post on my DB any more)
2. Adding a header in my fetching request,  such as:

   ```
   /******API SEACH****/
     /***Global Update***/
     private updateClients() {
       let xmlRequestPromise = fetch('https://wwwfrance1.CENSORED.eu.com/api/?apikey=CENSORED&service=list_clients',  {
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         }
       })
         .then(async response => this.clients = this.regexSearchClient(await response.text()))
       return xmlRequestPromise
     }
   ```

But that doesn't work either. I've verified that the header appears in the request.

How to proceed?

Comment: The server you're fetching from, needs to set it's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` or similar.

Comment: The header needs to be set on the server you're calling aka *"wwwfrance1.CENSORED.eu.com"*.

Comment: You **cannot** set CORS headers on the client. If you could, they'd be totally pointless. If you don't control the server, you'll need a _proxy_ of some kind to make those requests.

Comment: I'm going to try to setup a proxy. Is there any details i should implement to make the fetch pass ?

Comment: This question has hundreds of duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27

Answer (score 1):

Create your own server and make a route which fetches that API. From your Angular application fetch that route on your server.

Answer (score 0):

**What is CORS ?**

Cross-origin resource sharing is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

In simple terms only an internal webserver can send Requests which are potentially dangerous to it's web server, and requests from other server's are simply blocked.

But few HTTP requests are allowed ,Few of the allowed methods are GET, HEAD, POST.

**How do I resolve the issue ?**

Apparently in this circumstance you cannot send a fetch request to a web server having CORS header. Instead you can do a GET request to the web server as a web server having CORS allows HTTP GET requests.

**Note** - If you send a GET request to a web server using angular in your browser it wouldn't work as browser's convert GET requests into fetch requests and fetch requests aren't allowed from a web server with CORS. Instead send a GET request from a webserver/local machine rather than a browser.

Comment: I'm gonna try to move my fetching code in my Node.JS server and use get instead of fetch then. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as diagramed if the remote service which you are fetching from cannot be made (by whomever is hosting it or by you using configuration which they expose) to include CORS headers in its response. However, you can have your backend node application make the call instead of the frontend as CORS is enforced by the browser and your backend server is unlikely to be using a browser to make its requests. So, rather than your frontend fetching from the remote service, have it make a request to your backend, which can then make the request to the remote service, and reply from your backend to your frontend with whatever it needed from the remote service's response.

So long as your backend and frontend are served from the same protocol, hostname and port, CORS will not be an issue between them. If you plan to host them from different hostnames, ports, or protocols, you will need your backend to include CORS headers in its responses to allow your frontend to access your backend's resources. So long your requests are [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) a header like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my.frontend.dev:3000` will allow your frontend hosted with that protocol (https), hostname (my.frontend.dev), and port (3000) to access your backend's resources.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a package as a middleware. If you are using nodejs-framework expressjs.At first, you have to run `npm install cors -force`.Then add the code that is given bellow:-

```
const cors=require('cors')

app.use(cors({origin:true}))
```

Comment: I just did the following instruction,  in m nodeJS/express server, without success. I'm still facing the same error. Could it be because it's my front-end which fetch the website ? Is there a way to execute this code in a angular TS file ?

Comment: CORS cannot be fixed on the client side except in the case that the server will modify its response and add the necessary response headers based on a change to the request which is made to it.